# Broken baking texture

Tags: uv, texture-baking

When I do bake idmaps I get errors like these spots on the wings, even on texture 4096x, when in xNormal I wanted to bake AO from Hightpoly v. to Lowpoly I get similarly broken effect in same spots.
[image]
[image]
Merge by distance gives 0 verticles removed, select by non manifold residual walls and that in other places, normal in the right direction so what's wrong?

EDIT:
I get nice topology from Quad Remesher, it looks better but problem is still here[image]

Comment: Your topology is not very suitable for Blender, Quads are the most recommended and from the image it looks like sculpture or a scan. Try to make a retopology, then UV unwrap and then Bake the textures

Comment: i try to convert it to quads but no matter the method or program i either get too much vertex or the teeth of the model get destroyed

Comment: Retoplogy is mostly manual, automatic topology is not going to give a 100% good result, converting to quads does not qualify as Retoplogy either

Answer (score 1):

In Smart UV Project settings I changed Angle Limit to lower, to 28° and everything looks just fine now.